What exactly is DAX auto exists kicking in meaning?
I'm trying hard to understand the explanation from https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-dax-auto-exist/
The continent and country example is clear in the sense that Power BI only returns the existing pairs when these columns are used in the table visual.

Then they mention that the dax auto exists kicks in when we filter 2 columns of the same table. That is - Year and Language in the given example.
Subsequently they have shown an extended version of using the below measure in a visual:
# Projects All Time = CALCULATE (
    [# Projects],
    ALL ( Projects[Year] )
)

Which is:
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    TREATAS ( { "DAX", "Python" }, 'Projects'[Language] ),
    TREATAS ( { 2018 }, 'Projects'[Year] ),
    "Result", [# Projects All Time]
)

But I'm not understanding why after removing the 2018 filter can it not see all the DAX and Python rows?



Why is the # Projects All Time showing as 4? The author says this is because dax auto exists, ok, but why exactly is 2017 Python not included in count calculation? I need a simpler explanation to understand this.

Not sure what more you need but here is a recent example which might clarify how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78880700/powerbi-why-does-measure-produce-different-result-based-on-equivalent-filters/78886720#78886720

I'm not able to understand what does auto exists kicks in exactly mean. Why exactly is 2017 Python gone missing from the DAX calculation? Could you explain with the example. I understand 2 columns in filter (from same table) results in output of existing values rather than cross join. But why exactly does ALL not take off that filter?

Did the answers below helped you understand the situation ?

No, I'm not understanding why ALL is unable to remove the filter. Or does it remove the filter but underlying data doesn't have the value? I'm not able to think this clearly.

The COUNTROWS operation relies on SUMMARIZECOLUMNS behind the scenes, and to speed calculations auto-exists only returns results on dimensions with values. That works fine summarizing dimension tables but can misfire if the columns are in the same table.
In the example pivot table there is no value for DAX & 2018, so DAX first removes year filters (ALL Function), then after this runs it merges the slicer values and filters Python + DAX + 2018. Since Python + 2018 gives a blank result the Python rows are ignored thereafter to save query time.
Since it only runs a single query, that order of operations results in the extra Python project not being picked up by SUMMARIZECOLUMNS and not being part of the total. Recall that ALL executes first, then this auto-exists filter happens afterward.
The solution suggested is to use dimension tables, they show an example where separating out Year into a date table and Language into a dimension table avoids this issue. In this case ALL would clear the filter on the date table, and it would pick up the 2017 results because the filter on the fact table would only contain "Language," not language + year.
Basically using dimension tables will generate one filter per table, and that avoids the problem of multiple filters being combined into a single filter in the fact table, which in this case has the effect removing the 2017 row.

Would this also happed for Product and Category

I imagine it would be possible if they were in the same table and the combined filter result for Product+Category ending up being blank for the Category/product combination, then you tried to to remove filters on the same table. If you changed the years in the SQLBI example to "Language Category" you would still get the same result. If it is a concern it could be fixed with a simple calculated table containing only unique categories as a dimension. Then reference the dimension and not the fact table.

I'm trying to visualize but I think that would imply that a product can have more than one category though. If you have products with more than one category it can cause a lot of problems, for example unexpected results when context transitions happen.. that is also a good reason to use dimensions.

The above explanation is fine, but I find it helps to just think of this as a bug - it causes the product to produce results that are incorrect.  With that reframing, your challenge then becomes avoiding the bug, not trying to understand a "feature" that makes no sense.

Can you give me another example, other than YEAR and LANGUAGE to help me grasp this concept. For example PRODUCT and CATEGORY?

Assume someone changed the category name. Now just change the example to Year = Category, Language = Product. If a product does not exist under the new category name, then because the filter Category+Product from the slicer returns blank it will never look for that combination. This would be the same for year-category-product if a product was discontinued and not present in the current year. If the slicer combination returns a blank and you're not using dimension table then you have to be very cautious. The above comment is good advice, consider it a bug and try to avoid it.

AutoExist is a behavior in DAX where, when you apply filters on multiple columns from the same table, DAX automatically considers only the valid combinations of those columns.
To make it easy to explain, DAX eliminates combinations of column values that do not actually exist in the data.
The measure # Projects All Time is defined with the ALL ( Projects[Year] ) clause so here it removes the filter on the 'Year' column, essentially ignoring any filters applied to 'Year' in the visual but don't forget that the TREATAS still applies specific filters to 'Language' and 'Year'.
If I take this query :
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    TREATAS ( { "DAX", "Python" }, 'Projects'[Language] ),
    TREATAS ( { 2018 }, 'Projects'[Year] ),
    "Result", [# Projects All Time]
)

It applies two TREATAS filters so the Language filter will include "DAX" and "Python" and yhe Year filter will include only 2018.
If you remove the filter on 2018 from the measure, so the ALL ( Projects[Year] ) will allow all years to be considered.
However, AutoExist will kick in because you are filtering on both 'Language' and 'Year'.
DAX will look at the actual rows in the table where these columns overlap, and only valid combinations are taken into account. (I mean those that exist in the actual data)
Why Python in 2017 is not included ?
You might expect the "Python" row for 2017 to be counted, but it’s not because the TREATAS filter is specifically set to the year 2018. AutoExist will limit the combinations of 'Year' and 'Language' to only those combinations that exist.
In the 2018 filter context, the only valid 'Language' values in the table are for 'DAX', so it doesn’t consider Python in 2017.
Why is the count 4?
In 2018, I see that the combination of rows where 'Language' is either DAX or Python results in valid rows for DAX only, and the measure ignores any 2017 Python rows due to the filter.
So the measure returns the count for the DAX projects in 2018 (4 projects), and Python in 2017 isn't considered.
Try to think it in this way :

DAX AutoExist ensures that the combinations of columns you filter by are actually present in the data.
When you filter by both 'Year' and 'Language', AutoExist removes any impossible combinations.
Even though the year filter is removed, the rows for "Python 2017" don’t match the valid year and language combinations left after applying TREATAS.


Is this a feature or bug or just the way it is.

Also, why does ALL ( Projects[Year] ) apply to output of TREATAS and not full table?
